Installing a github package without setup.py
I was hoping to install a package from the github for my python env, but there is no setup.py file, so I got an error when I'm trying to pip install git+. Without dealing with this matter, I always get another error saying -"bash: dip-c: command not found".
This is the GitHub page and the package name is 'dip-c' https://github.com/tanlongzhi/dip-c
Could you guys advise me on installing this package in my environment? Thank you so much in advance!
(I just git clone the package and moved the package under the one of the PATH, but when I ran dip-c command, there was an error saying "bash: dip-c: command not found".)

It is not a Python nor Github package. It's just some code.
You download or clone it, install the dependencies manually, and run it.
When you run it, you either have to put it in a directory in your PATH, or run it with the full path to the dip-c executable.

❌ dip-c
✅  /path/to/dip-c


(I just git clone the package and moved the package under the one of the PATH, but when I ran dip-c command, there was an error saying "bash: dip-c: command not found".)

The dip-c executable must be in a PATH directory, not a sub-directory. For example, if /this/is/in/your/path/ is in your PATH and you cloned to /this/is/in/your/path/dip-c/ it would not work. You would need /this/is/in/your/path/dip-c/ to be in your PATH.
It's simpler to make a symbolic link of the dip-c executable into your PATH. ln -s /path/to/dip-c/dip-c /some/dir/in/your/path/dip-c
